# How to use NSColorList in swift3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I was trying to create a NSColorList in Swift3

```
import UIKit
...
let list = NSColorList(name: "mylist")
```

But XCode complains Use of unresolved identifier NSColorList. Am I missing something here?

Comment: `NSColorList` is only for macOS. Look at the documentation.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`NSColorList`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nscolorlist) is for macOS, not iOS.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know